# Rx Need help in writing hierarchy for the classes

Tags: c#-4.0, factory, system.reactive

I used 101 samples of Rx Framework ( http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc47 ) last example and created a class like below and usage like in the test function.

---

```
private void Test()
{
    var order = new Order();
    order.ObservableOrder.Subscribe(
        ord => Console.WriteLine("Order progress "),  // subscribe to onnext event
        ex => Console.WriteLine("Paid error " + ex.Message),   // subscribe to error event
        () => Console.WriteLine("Paid oncompleted ")  // subscribe to completed event
      ); // Subscribe

     order.Start();
 }


 public class Order
 {
      private readonly Subject<Order> _subject = new Subject<Order>();
      public IObservable<Order> ObservableOrder { get { return _subject.AsObservable(); } }

      public void RaiseError() {
         _subject.OnError(new Exception("test exception"));
      }
      public void RaiseCompleted() {
          _subject.OnCompleted();
      }
      public void RaiseProgress() {
          _subject.OnNext(this);
      }

      public void Start() {
             for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                   this.RaiseProgress();

              this.RaiseError(); // either error is raised 
              this.RaiseCompleted();  // or completed is raised
      }
    }
```

My requirement is how to write a base class ( or some kind of factory ) to
make it easy to use this for 20-30 classes which does similar things ( like they need to
send progress, oncompleted and on error events ) Also how can I also send some data back to
on progress and oncompleted events ( like we send exception into onerror event )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OnCompleted()` accepts no arguments, which obviously can't be changed.

You have a few choices:

You can create a payload class that has both the process and the final payload in it. `class OrderProgress { double Process; OrderResult Result; }`

You can expose another subject, `Progress`, which you can subscribe to in addition to `ObservableOrder`.

If you want to keep `Start` reentrant, you could have it return an object that exposed both a `Progress` and `OrderProgress` observable.

**Edit:** Including example code (of my second option):

```
private void Test() 
{ 
    var order = new Order(); 

    order.ObservableProgress.Subscribe( 
        prog => Console.WriteLine("Order progress " + prog.ToString()
    );

    order.ObservableOrder.Subscribe( 
        ord => Console.WriteLine("Order progress"),
        ex => Console.WriteLine("Paid error " + ex.Message), 
        () => Console.WriteLine("Paid oncompleted")
    );

    order.Start(); 
}


public class Order 
{ 
    private readonly Subject<Order> _subject = new Subject<Order>(); 
    private readonly Subject<double> _progressSubject = new Subject<double>(); 

    public IObservable<Order> ObservableOrder
    {
        get { return _subject.AsObservable(); }
    }

    public IObservable<double> ObservableProgress
    {
        get { return _progressSubject.AsObservable(); }
    }

    public void RaiseError() { 
        _subject.OnError(new Exception("test exception")); 
    } 

    public void RaiseCompleted() {
        _subject.OnNext(this); 
        _subject.OnCompleted(); 

        _progressSubject.OnCompleted();
    } 

    public void RaiseProgress(double progress) { 
        _progressSubject.OnNext(progress); 
    } 

    public void Start() { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
            this.RaiseProgress((double)i / 5D); 

        this.RaiseError(); // either error is raised  
        this.RaiseCompleted();  // or completed is raised 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Richard,
   That was little hard for me to understand as I am still a newbie to Rx and some of the advanced .net stuff. Will you be kind enough to change my sample code ( or give pointers ) so I have
1) if possible have a baseclass which have the common code  like RaiseError etc RaiseFunctions  and also the _subject and ObservableClass  
2) How to pass args back to the subscriber of events some data ( like onError can pass an exception

Comment: @john - Not a problem. Let me know whether I can elaborate further. Otherwise, mark the answer as the "the answer" (the click to the left) if it has enough information to answer your question.